# Output of terminal commes all at once instead of line by line in windows and not in MAC

Tags: java, swing, terminal, command, real-time

I'm writing a program which makes use of a compiled version of a .c file for each OS. I want to show the output of this program which runs in the terminal/command prompt in real time.

I've tested a simplified version of my program to prove that it works properly while interacting with the terminal or console. This is the code:

```
package mcve;

import com.sun.glass.ui.Window;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javax.swing.*;

public class WindowsVsMacExample {

    JDialog dialog;
    JTextArea textArea;
    JProgressBar bar;

    public WindowsVsMacExample() {
        new BackgroundTask().execute();
    }

    private void getLoadingGUI() {
        dialog = new JDialog();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

        textArea = new JTextArea(20, 20);

        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane();
        sp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Output:"));
        sp.setViewportView(textArea);

        bar = new JProgressBar();
        bar.setIndeterminate(true);

        JPanel barPanel = new JPanel();
        barPanel.add(bar);

        panel.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(barPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        dialog.setContentPane(panel);
        dialog.setUndecorated(true);
        dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        dialog.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        dialog.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class BackgroundTask extends SwingWorker<Integer, String> {

        private int status;

        public BackgroundTask() {
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground() {
            try {
                List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();//Create command
                command.add("ping");
                String name = System.getProperty("os.name");
                if (name.startsWith("Win")) {
                    command.add("-n");
                } else {
                    command.add("-c");
                }
                command.add("10");
                command.add("google.com");

                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command); //Create process
                pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
                Process p = pb.start();
                String s;
                BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                while ((s = stdout.readLine()) != null && !isCancelled()) {
                    publish(s);
                }
                if (!isCancelled()) {
                    status = p.waitFor();
                }
                p.getInputStream().close();
                p.getOutputStream().close();
                p.getErrorStream().close();
                p.destroy();
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
            return status;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(java.util.List<String> messages) {
            for (String message : messages) {
                textArea.append(message + "\n");
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            bar.setIndeterminate(false);
            dialog.dispose();
            System.out.println("Command finished, dialog disposed.");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JButton button = new JButton("Ping google");
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.add(button);
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("Ping start.");
                        WindowsVsMacExample example = new WindowsVsMacExample();
                        example.getLoadingGUI();
                        System.out.println("Loading dialog displayed");
                    }
                });
                frame.add(panel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I switched from ping to this .c program compiled for each OS, in the MAC OS system it works properly by showing the output in real time. But when I run it in windows the output dialog doesn't show anything because all the text comes at the end. I can see in the output of netbeans that it worked but as an user you don't see anything, it does what it is supposed to do but doesn't show what it is doing.

If I run this program from the command prompt in windows it works as it should by showing each line while it is doing the task.

So, if the program works when I execute it in windows, and what I've programmed works perfectly in MAC where can be the problem? I've been almost all day trying to get the reason of this but I can find an explanation.